# Pearson's chi-square goodness of fit test

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

I am trying to perform a Pearson's chi-square goodness of fit test on my Generalized Linear Model to measure how well the model fits my data.

Below is my code:

```
m1.pearson <- residuals(m1, type = "pearson")
pchisq(sum(m1.pearson^2), m1$df.residual)
```

My question is: if the value given by the command `pchisq(sum(m1.pearson^2), m1$df.residual)` is very high, does it imply that the model fit is good?

Comment: Can we see all of the code? What was the glm command that you ran?

Comment: You have asked two nearly identical questions in the last few minutes. I responded to the other one. Please delete one or the other; if you like, you can edit one so that it contains both questions.

Comment: What is "very high"?  $0.01$?  $0.99$?